# Copy the value of a property in the properties drawer

Tags: org-mode, kill-ring, org-properties

I want to copy the value of a property in the properties drawer to the kill ring, so I can paste (yank) it with `org-yank` (for example). Something similar to what `kill-ring-save` does.

Currently, I have to open the properties drawer, select (mark) the property value, and copy it to the kill ring with `kill-ring-save`. Then move to the destination and paste it using `org-yank`. I would like to use a key binding to copy the value of a specific property (for example `:ID:`) so I don't have to do all the selection procedure.

Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function should do it. You can bind it to a key.

```lisp
(defun copy-id-property ()
  "copy the id property of current heading"
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (org-entry-get (point) "ID")))
```

Comment: There's no interactive way to get it? We have org-set-property, but there's no equivalent org-get-property?